# Есть принципиальная разница в использовании lock-free подходов CAS в прикладном коде и MVCC в базах данных?

Tags: база-данных, алгоритм, lock-free, cas

Пример использования [CAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap#:%7E:text=In%20computer%20science%2C%20compare%2Dand,to%20a%20new%20given%20value.) брал [тут](https://habr.com/ru/post/459514/)

```
do
{
  comparand = eventHandler;
  eventHandler = Interlocked.CompareExchange<EventHandler>(ref this.MyEvent, (EventHandler) Delegate.Combine((Delegate) comparand, (Delegate) value), comparand);
}
while (eventHandler != comparand);
```

[MVCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) описание использования взял [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C_%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9) (как я понял это именно эта технология):

> Read committed
>
> Сохранение нескольких версий параллельно изменяемых строк.
> При каждом изменении строки СУБД создаёт новую версию этой строки, с которой продолжает работать изменившая данные транзакция, в то время как любой другой «читающей» транзакции возвращается последняя зафиксированная версия. Преимущество такого подхода в том, что он обеспечивает бо́льшую скорость, так как предотвращает блокировки. Однако он требует, по сравнению с первым, существенно бо́льшего расхода оперативной памяти, которая тратится на хранение версий строк. Кроме того, при параллельном изменении данных несколькими транзакциями может создаться ситуация, когда несколько параллельных транзакций произведут несогласованные изменения одних и тех же данных (поскольку блокировки отсутствуют, ничто не помешает это сделать). Тогда та транзакция, которая зафиксируется первой, сохранит свои изменения в основной БД, а остальные параллельные транзакции окажется невозможно зафиксировать (так как это приведёт к потере обновления первой транзакции). Единственное, что может в такой ситуации СУБД — это откатить остальные транзакции и выдать сообщение об ошибке «Запись уже изменена».

Понятно что CAS именно для свапа, а MVCC вообще в контексте баз данных. Идея применения показалась похожей - если другой процесс/поток/транзакция успел раньше текущей выполнить действие, то действия текущей откатить и возможно начать попытку заново.

**UPDATE**

Пробую переформулировать. Места использования и задачи разные. MVCC  более общий, а CAS вообще для 1 задачи.

Но в двух описаниях/примерах есть что-то что происходит, к примеру обмен данными или обновление записи в БД.
В конце двух подходов идет проверка если кто-то другой менял данные, то операция не успешна.
Привильно я понимаю что это на самом деле один и тот же подход/концепция избежать блокировок? Или есть разные подходы lock-free, не только на основе версий? Может есть не только CAS для прикладного кода, а и какое-то обобщение как и MVCC для баз данных.

Comment: Я не понял вопроса. Можете как то переформулировать?

Comment: @tym32167 Попробовал, переформулировать. Что-то понятно? Стоит такой вопрос оставлять или он слишком...?

Comment: всё, что я понял из вопроса - это то, что ну есть 2 разные задачи. Есть 2 разных решения разных задач. Две задачи связывает только то, что они обе решают проблемы конкурентного доступа к данным. Я не знаю, относится это к lock-free или не относится и почему это может быть важно. Interlocked делает операцию атомарной, MVCC видмо группирует набор операций в транзакцию. Атомарность 1 операции и атомарность транзакции - это вещи разные. Вот тот же Interlocked.Increment - он тоже атомарный, но ему по барабану на степень параллелизма, он не фейлится, а просто выполняет операции последовательно.

Comment: Потому я написанное вами понимаю, я не понимаю, в чем вопрос. С чем сложности то?